MaterialUI useTheme returning wrong theme in nested layout
I have a layout:
export default function WebLayout() {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={DefaultTheme}>
            <CssBaseline />
            {children}
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}

And another nested layout:
export default function DashboardLayout() {
    const theme = useTheme()

    return (
        <WebLayout>
            <div className="dashboard">
                {children}
            </div>
        </WebLayout>
    )
}

If I console.log(DefaultTheme) on WebLayout, I get my default theme perfectly.
But if I console.log(theme) on DashboardLayout, I get a different theme.
Why is that?

React Providers should wrap the component. If your useSomething hooks needs a provider, that provider cannot be a component's child.

Ahh makes sense, thank you!!
